# If text over flow = It goes to next line

Tags: html, css

How do i make the text go to second line, if it overflows? [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bj7smxL3/)

Code

```css
.maincard {
overflow-y: hidden;
white-space: nowrap;
}

.card {
display:inline-block;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    transition: 0.3s;
    width: 200px;
}

.card:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.container {
    padding: 2px 16px;
}
```

```html
<h2>Card</h2>
<div class="maincard">
<div class="card">
  <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:100%">
  <div class="container">
    <h4><b>My name is John Doeeeee And Help meeee</b></h4> 
  </div>
</div>
<div class="card">
  <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:100%">
  <div class="container">
    <h4><b>John Doeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee</b></h4> 
  </div>
</div>
<div class="card">
  <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:100%">
  <div class="container">
    <h4><b>John Doeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee</b></h4> 
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

One method is using: display:inline-table, but this is not exactly what i want. It do not send the test to 2nd line.

Comment: You just want the text below the image to go on a second line? in the `.maincard` class you have a css rule called `white-space: nowrap;` get rid of it and it'll display on another line?

Comment: `.maincard {
  display: flex;
}`   hope this will works for you .. margin, padding all other add based on your needs

Comment: [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/jcuqdqhr/)

Comment: does the title asks a question or makes a statement? **unclear**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use `white-space: nowrap` on the `.maincard` to keep all cards on the same line. This definition is inherited by the internal `.card` items, and the `<h4>`, and prevent the text from wrapping.
Restore white-space wrapping to normal on the `.card`, and align the cards to 
the top:

```
.card {
  display: inline-block;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transition: 0.3s;
  width: 200px;
  vertical-align: top;
  white-space: normal;
}
```

```css
.maincard {
  overflow-y: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.card {
  display: inline-block;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transition: 0.3s;
  width: 200px;
  vertical-align: top;
  white-space: normal;
}

.card:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.container {
  padding: 2px 16px;
}
```

```html
<h2>Card</h2>
<div class="maincard">
  <div class="card">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:100%">
    <div class="container">
      <h4><b>My name is John Doeeeee And Help meeee</b></h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:100%">
    <div class="container">
      <h4><b>John Doeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee</b></h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:100%">
    <div class="container">
      <h4><b>John Doeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee</b></h4>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
     overflow: auto;
     white-space: nowrap;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     padding: 5px;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one :
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1pkvh6zr/)

```
.maincard {
   overflow-y: hidden;
   white-space: pre-line;
}

.maincard .container,
.maincard .container * {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here is 2 ways:**

> A) Use of : `word-wrap: break-word;` Property.

```
.container {
    padding: 2px 16px;
    white-space: normal;<---------------Added
    word-wrap: break-word;<-------------Added
}
```

```css
.maincard {
overflow-y: hidden;
white-space: nowrap;
}

.card {
display:inline-block;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    transition: 0.3s;
    width: 200px;
}

.card:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.container {
    padding: 2px 16px;
    white-space: normal;
    word-wrap: break-word;

}
```

```html
<h2>Card</h2>
<div class="maincard">
<div class="card">
  <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:100%">
  <div class="container">
    <h4><b>My name is John Doeeeee And Help meeee</b></h4> 
  </div>
</div>
<div class="card">
  <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:100%">
  <div class="container">
    <h4><b>John Doeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee</b></h4> 
  </div>
</div>
<div class="card">
  <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:100%">
  <div class="container">
    <h4><b>John Doeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee</b></h4> 
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

> B) Use of : `word-break: break-all;` Property.

```
.container {
    padding: 2px 16px;
    white-space: normal;<---------------Added
    word-break: break-all;<-------------Added
}
```

```css
.maincard {
overflow-y: hidden;
white-space: nowrap;
}

.card {
display:inline-block;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    transition: 0.3s;
    width: 200px;
}

.card:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.container {
    padding: 2px 16px;
    white-space: normal;
    word-break: break-all;

}
```

```html
<h2>Card</h2>
<div class="maincard">
<div class="card">
  <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:100%">
  <div class="container">
    <h4><b>My name is John Doeeeee And Help meeee</b></h4> 
  </div>
</div>
<div class="card">
  <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:100%">
  <div class="container">
    <h4><b>John Doeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee</b></h4> 
  </div>
</div>
<div class="card">
  <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:100%">
  <div class="container">
    <h4><b>John Doeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee</b></h4> 
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```